# Is old keystore key info cached somewhere during generate apk for React Native Android?

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I input password with a typo during generated a signing key, but put the correct password in build.gradle. After I put typo one in build.gradle. Seems the correct was cached. Then I generated another key. But it always shows the following error. Are those values cached somewhere (Like "storeFile file", storePassword, keyPassword)? How can I fix it?

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>
> /[project folder]/android/app/myapp-release-key-old.keystore (No such
>   file or directory)

1. Env: Mac pro laptop; react-native: 0.59.5
2. Command run (under andorid sub folder):

> ./gradlew assembleRelease

(Same error in Andorid Studio->Build->Generate Signed Build or APK)

3. /[project folder]/android/app/build.gradle:

> ```
> signingConfigs {
>     release {
>         storeFile file("myapp-release-key-new.keystore")
>         keyAlias "myapp-release-key-new"
>         storePassword "***"
>         keyPassword "***"
>     }
> } ...
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
>         signingConfig signingConfigs.release
>     }
> }
> ```

What I tried:

1. Verified no similar value in  ~/.gradle and delete properties file there
2. clean ~/.gradleas/caches
3. reboot Mac laptop
4. sudo keytool -delete -alias myapp-release-key-old -keystore myapp-release-key-old.keystore
5. removed old key file